# AppManage error: Failed to create adjustment process

Tags: tibco, businessworks, tibco-business-works

When attempting to deploy a TIBCO BusinessWorks project using TIBCO TRA AppManage for example:

> D:\projects\MyProject>D:\tibco\tra\5.7\bin\AppManage --propFile "D:\tibco\tra\5.7\bin\AppManage.tra" -deploy -ear build\MyProject.ear -deployConfig build\MyProject.xml -app /Projects/MyProject -user myuser -domain DEV -pw secret

Deployment fails with the following error:

> Failed to create adjustment process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.exe` to the AppManage command:

> D:\projects\MyProject>D:\tibco\tra\5.7\bin\AppManage**.exe** --propFile "D:\tibco\tra\5.7\bin\AppManage.tra" -deploy -ear build\MyProject.ear -deployConfig build\MyProject.xml -app /Projects/MyProject -user myuser -domain DEV -pw secret`

This may be related to the version of the operating system (without `.exe` works fine on Windows 7 but not on Windows Server 2008 R2).